# Timestamp doesn't change in string format

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

```
let dateFormater : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormater.date(from: "2016-11-11T11:42:27Z")
print("date is  ---->%@",date)

let timestamp = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
print("timestamp is  ---->%@",timestamp!)

let str =  String(format: "%@",timestamp!)
print("str value is ---->%@",str)

date is -----> 2016-11-11 11:42:27 +000
timestamp is----->1478864547.0
str value is-----> null
```

Getting date and time stamp value. How to change `timestamp` value into string. Means `1478864547.0`(timestampvalue) to string formate

`let str =  String(format: "%@",timestamp!)` whats wrong this line.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `let timestampInString = "\(timestamp)"`.

If it is optional then

```
if let timestamp = date?.timeIntervalSince1970 {
     let timestampInString = "\(timestamp)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nirav I am able to print value

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `timestamp` is not an object - it's a `TimeInterval` (which is just a `typealias` for `Double`). If you want to use a formatted string, you need to do `"%lf"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null value. `timestamp` is not a `String` value so you can no get a `String` value directly, You have to use `Float` to `String` Casting
Do as follow I am sure it will work for you.

```
let dateFormater : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormater.date(from: "2016-11-11T11:42:27Z")
print("date is  ---->%@",date)

let timestamp = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
print("timestamp is  ---->%@",timestamp!)

let str =  String(format: "%0.0f",timestamp!)
print("str value is ---->%@",str)
```

TimeInterval is typealias for Double, So use or " 0.0f " " %lf ".